# How to switch between the windows in chrome using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I opened two browser windows, One is my Main window and second one is incognito. How to switch to the main window. When i invoke incognito ,window's focus switched to 2nd (incognito) window. Now i want to switch back to the previous main window. Please suggest the possible way out !!

Code i'm using:

// 1. Invoked Chrome browser.

2. Invoked a new browser in incognito mode.

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("incognito");
   options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```
3. Performed some task in incognito window.
4. Now i want to switch back to main window without closing incognito one.

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch windows using window_handles:

```
window_first = driver.window_handles[0]
window_second = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_second)
```

Comment: Could you please share the complete code for this ?

Comment: @daisy So you talk about an incognito session and a normal one, right?